# Zapier Cli: Not able to set authentication.connectionLabel dynamically

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

Following the developer docs, I have attempted numerous variations trying to achieve this.

I would like to extract the label from the token payload, if not I can build it from the /me response body.

This is my latest attempt:

```js
var jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');

const getTokenFields = (z, bundle) => {
  var sub = jwtDecode(bundle.authData.token)['sub']
  console.log(sub)
  return sub;
};

const getLabelField = (z, bundle) => {
  var sub = jwtDecode(bundle.authData.token)['sub']['label']
  console.log(sub)
  return sub;
};

const authentication = {
    type: 'session',
    test: {
        url: '{{process.env.AP_HOST}}/me'
    },
    fields: [
        {
            key: 'token',
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            helpText: 'See settings to get your token'
        }
    ],
    sessionConfig: {
        perform: getTokenFields
    },
    connectionLabel: {
        perform: getLabelField
    }
};

module.exports = authentication;
```

the only thing that I can get to work is:
`connectionLabel: "{{bundle.authData.token}}"`, but it looks terrible!

`connectionLabel: "{{bundle.authData.responsefield}}"` feels like it should be something that should work but it doesn't either

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Instead of `connectionLabel: {perform: getLabelField}`, it should just be `connectionLabel: getLabelField`. You can also use a string that pulls from the bundle (like you're seeing) or any data that comes back from the designated test endpoint (see [here](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/ZDW010/)).

There *should* be validation that prevents what you have (that'll error when you run `zapier validate`) but if that comes back clean then definitely let us know.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your suggestion.

When I try the following, it does pass validation, however in Zapier it does not show the correct label, it generates "#2" as the label

Comment: `connectionLabel: getLabelFromToken`